# Ionic 2 - Keyboard Not Hiding on Form Input(text area). Issue present in iOS devices, android works fine

Tags: ios, ionic2, blur, ionic-keyboard

When the user taps outside the input fields the keyboard is not hiding. Using ionic-plugin-keyboard on ionic 2. The UI template is as following,

```
<ion-content padding id="ten" no-bounce>
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="infoText">{{ "PLEASEENTER" | translate}}<br>{{"name" | translate}}</div>
<div>
<form [formGroup] = "tn" id="tn">
<ion-item id="inputItem"  [ngClass] = "{'requiredField' : requiredFieldNotFilled}">
    <ion-textarea #input class="mediumFontInput" clearInput ="false"  type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" placeholder = "{{'NAME' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="search" (input)="searchList($event)" (focus)="setCursorPosition($event)" ></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
</form>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.